# Forward touches to a view and cause UIGetureRecognizer to begin

Tags: iphone, ipad, gesture-recognition

Is there a way to forward touches to a subview which has a gesture recognizer attached, and that the forwarded events will initiate the gesture recognizer?

Comment: Hmm, what are you trying to do here that would require processing touches at multiple different layers of views?

Comment: Want to detect when a a movement is continuing over onto a view which has a gesture recognizer. In this case it is not enough to forward the touch events as the gesture recognizer should receive the events before this and not as a result of the views touch events.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work with a little workaround (might not be suitable in all cases...).
Because UIGestureRecognizers get their events from the sendEvent method before UIViews do,
I created a custom 'ForwarderGestureRecognizer' on the outer view and all this view does is to forward the events to the recognizers of the subview view when required.

Comment: Hi LK, I have same issue can you please explain briefly with code how you did this?